# How to fix error, Iterator was not declared in this scope'' and ''Iterator does not name a type'

Tags: c++, templates

I was practicing standard template library and in that when i replaced vector::iterator itr; with auto itr; there was an error saying that itr was not declared in the scope and itr does not name a type.

I  included iterator header file but the error was not fixed.

```
auto itr= v.begin();
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
for(; itr!=v.end();itr++){
    cout<<"Value => "<<*itr<<endl;
}
```

expected result- 10 20 30 40
actual result- errors
  itr was not declared in the scope
  itr does not name a type

Comment: What compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: That's minimal but not a [mcve]. You should add the (guessing roundabout 5) lines to make it one.

Comment: Btw. Why not `for (auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)`? 1. I wouldn't assign iterators when container is changed afterwards. This might not be an issue for `std::vector` but is IMHO an underhanded source of errors when code is changed. 2. Postfix increment might be more expensive than prefix increment. Whenever there is no need for postfix (and there rarely is) then I prefer prefix.

Comment: What is v? My glas ball is broken, sorry!

Comment: Are you compiling with at least [`c++11`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) support?

Comment: @r3musn0x I am using codeblocks.

Comment: @Klaus v is name of vector. Sry i did not mention it.

Comment: @Scheff i implemented for loop the way u said, assigned it inside the loop but the error is still there.

Comment: This was already hinted in the answer as well as in multiple comments. Again: Which compiler do you use on which platform? Did you enable at least C++11 support? (An older version might be the default if your compiler is aged.) Out of curiosity, I fiddled a bit on [**Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/vNkBu2). 1. Please, note the few lines I had to add to get a [mcve]. 2. gcc 4.6.4 doesn't even support `-std=c++11`; gcc 4.7.3 fails without `-std=c++11` but works with `-std=c++11`. Please, note also that gcc **9**.1 is released meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the compiler doesn't regard `auto` as a type. Try argument `-std=c++11` for g++ compiler. For MSVC, configure the supported standard in properties window.